# How to hide a column in a list, dynamically in cognos?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

Actually I'm working on Cognos 10.1 .
I have three prompts (Value prompt) in my report. All the prompts are optional. Based on the selections I wanna show the results. Each prompt corresponds to a column in the list. If the value is chosen in the prompt, it has to show the column. Else, it has to hide the column. We should not use conditional blocks or style variables. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, "not use conditional blocks or style variables"? They are aimed for this purpose. It's like saying create a list report without the list component. That's almost impossible.

Comment: @Ran Avnon, Yeah, I agree, but I'd like to know whether the same is possible through any other means. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - Here is how i did this before.  I created a prompt page that allowed the user to pick the columns they wanted on the report via check boxes(true/false).  Each check box represented a unique parameter name associated with a column you later want visible or invisible.

On the report page, the default state of the list shows all the possible columns.  In order to conditionally hide the columns i created a Conditional Style(one for each column) and associated that with the list column/cell.  The conditional style basically says hey if my param was not chosen false then set the "box-type to none which means it will not be rendered at all.

You do have to create a conditional style for each column, but when trying to make something flexible/dynamic and easy for the user its worth it.  Mine also allowed dynamic sorting/grouping(up to 3 levels) for the same set of columns)

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, but still I'd like to elaborate my requirement. I'd like to know whether dynamic hiding of a column is possible without the user's choice. ie. The dynamic hiding of a column should be done only based on some condition but not on the user's choice.

Comment: Absolutely... At that point you would use a conditional style linked to a list/singleton query results and that conditional style/block is just like an if condition.  You can created conditional variables/styles based off of parameters/data returned from queries etc... and you can link the true/false or case based results of those the report/html components to control their style such as visible/box type/font size/background images and a ton of other stuff.  Combining these features along with the ability to embed HTML/Javascript makes almost anything possible.